# How to click on Continue button, present in the Salesforce application?

Tags: webdriver

I am unable to click the Continue button present in the screen. Following is the code which I am using, 
LoginPage2.driver.findElement(By.name("Continue")).click();

Two buttons are placed side by side  Continue and Cancel. I am able to click on the Cancel button using the same command, but not the former one.

Following is the HTML format:

<*input value="Continue" class="btn" title="Continue" name="save" type="submit">

<*input value="Cancel" class="btn" title="Cancel" name="cancel" type="submit">

Kindly help..

Regards,
Sambit

Comment: Well what page? What exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
LoginPage2.driver.findElement(By.name("save")).click();
```

Or

```
LoginPage2.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Continue']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

See your HTML elements: 
`LoginPage2.driver.findElement(By.name("Continue")).click();`

It didn't work because `By.name` is wrong and it is correct in case of cancel. Instead of `By.name` you should use `By.value("Continue")` than it will work.